# CSS and HTML - Header fixed with scrollable table

Tags: html, css

I almost tried everything. I have a table header css like this

```
TH.thr4
{
BORDER-RIGHT: aliceblue 1px solid;
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
BORDER-TOP: aliceblue 1px solid;
PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
FONT-WEIGHT: bolder;
FONT-SIZE: 12px;
FLOAT: left;
PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
MARGIN: 0px;
BORDER-LEFT: aliceblue 1px solid;
WIDTH: 0px;
COLOR: navy;
PADDING-TOP: 0px;
BORDER-BOTTOM: aliceblue 1px solid;
FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial;
HEIGHT: 17px;
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d4e2ff;
TEXT-ALIGN: right;
FONT-VARIANT: small-caps;
position:fixed;
z-index:9999;
}
```

But still header is not getting fixed. What am i missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by fixed, what's the expected outcome ?

Comment: Fixed as in i should see header every time when i scroll the rows

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try some plugins.. May be this will help you

[Codrops Tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/09/sticky-table-headers-columns/)